# How does the Turbulence Force Field work?

Tags: force-fields

I am doing a series of experiments with smoke & fire. I found a blend file that uses the Turbulence force field in a fire simulation. During the simulation the force field is moved along the Z-axis starting below the fire and ending above the fire.

[image]

How does the turbulence force field work exactly and what is the impact of the various settings ? There is not much info in the manual and I cannot find adequate tutorials.

Comment: I like to think of it almost like a displacement modifier for particles.

Comment: OK so after reading up it seems that turbulence is just a vector field generated by Perlin noise.  I'll add a full answer after some more research.

Comment: That would be great !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A force field is a [*vector field*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field), meaning at every point in space it defines a [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) based on some vector-valued function.  In the case of a force field, the vectors represent forces pushing the particles around.   In other words, at each frame the force field exerts a force on every particle dependant on the particle's position.

What differs between the different force fields is the vector function they are based on.  For a turbulence field it uses some noise pattern ([Perlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise), I think), creating random "turbulent" particle movement.  Most of the settings for the force field (the ones that change when you change the force field type) modify this noise pattern.

**TL;DR:** The turbulence force field pushes particles around based on their position in a 3D noise.

---

Here's a rough explanation of the key settings:

- **Strength** controls the amount of force the field exerts on the particles.  Note that this is a multiplier to the strength given by the noise texture so it' actually a maximum value since the noise gives values from 0 to 1.
- **Size** is the scale of the noise texture.  Larger values (compared to the scale of your scene) will make the particles move in bigger masses, while small values will produce more chaotic movement.
- **Noise** is the amount distortion applied to the noise texture.  Higher values will make the particle movement tighter and more erratic.
- Falloff - **Type** (Sphere/Tube/Cone) changes the shape of the falloff zone.
- Falloff - **Power** changes the polynomial power, essentially the steepness, of the falloff.  A value of 0 here means no falloff, meaning all particles are affected by the force field equally no matter their relation to it.
- Falloff - **Minimum/Maximum** changes the start and end point of the falloff curve.  The force field is in full effect for all particles closer than the minimum and does not effect particles beyond the maximum at all.

Comment: Could you say something about turbulence and fire ? Is the distance between the position of the force field and the fire important ?

Comment: @OldMan I'm working on an explanation of the settings, including falloff, right now.  It might be a little while though.

Comment: What is exactly the impact of the force field on fire ? Where would it differ from wind ?

Comment: You speak about a noise texture. What noise texture ? How are "Strength" and "Noise" different as both seem to have an impact on he distortion of the noise texture

Comment: Are FLOW and SEED also important ?

Comment: @OldMan  [Seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) just changes the randomness for the noise pattern.  I am not really sure what flow does though but I can't see much of a visible change when used.  That might warrant a new question.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will configure some different setups for the Turbulence force field now and use it to create some randomness in fire simulations. I will post here a link when I have some

Comment: could you maybe explain a bit more what you mean with "noise texture" ?

Comment: @OldMan  It uses the noise texture's value at each particle's position to determine the direction and magnitude of the force applied to the particle.

Comment: for me the whole concept of a "noise texture" is new. I don't know what it is. I have trouble to basically understand what that is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49789/discussion-between-pgmath-and-old-man).